# Does Spring Boot automatically map user input to an object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, lombok

Given some controller that processes input based on a class `Contact` with several fields:

```
@PostMapping(value="")
public String addContactMessage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("contact") Contact contact, Model model) {
    // this will print the name provided in the input, without me explicitly saying contact.setName(name)
    System.out.println(contact.getName();
    return "index.html";
}
```

... assuming that my Contact class has a `private String name` attribute, with a getter and a setter, and I also have an `addContact.html` page with a `text field` of `name="name"`, when I try to print `contact.getName()` on screen, Spring Boot returns the name of the contact I entered via the textfield.

That's good, in my opinion, but my question is: why? I didn't even mention a `@RequestParam()` inside the controller's parameters and I didn't even instantiate the `contact` reference, in order to later assign the user input.

Tried googling about it, but found nothing, to be honest. Could it be from the **Validation** plugin? My `Contact` class has several annotations added, too, including Lombok's the `@Data` annotation, but removing them all and manually writing getters and setters would still result in this "auto-mapping". Removing the getters and setters will stop this process from happening.

Also, it seems that the input names should be the same (ignoring case sensitivity) with the class field names (for example, for a field called `message`, I should have an input with `name="message"`).

My question is, is this a Spring thing? Why does this happen? What happens if I have, for example, three method parameters of type `Contact`? Will it map user input to all three of them?

Comment: How do you reach addContact.html page, does that controller method have setAttribute with instance of contact, what are the contents of form tag. The answer lies in these questions

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao `addContact.html` will be reached with a `@GetMapping` controller method. No attributes are sent through some model.

Comment: All such MVC frameworks provide a way to directly push the request parameters on the  model i.e. data class directly. This is done to reduce the boilerplate code we used to do in servlets where we fetched request parameter values, convert them to appropriate datatype, and set on model class using setter methods which then introduced form beans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is done by the Spring 's Databinder stuff which you can find more info about it at [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods).

Basically it try to get the values from the HTTP request 's query parameters and the submitted form data , and set it to the model 's properties by calling the corresponding public setter following the [JavaBeans naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javabeans-spec.html). For example , for the query parameter which the name is `foo` , it will look for the setter `setFoo(String val)` in the model to set the value to it.

For the codes about how does it work , you can refer to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/16ea4692bab551800b9ba994ac08099e8acfd6cd/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java#L126) as the starting point.

If the controller method has 3 parameters of the type `Contact` , both of them will have the same value bounded to them but they are different instances.